# HTML required attribute doesn't work with google recaptcha

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

Require attribute **on the input field** doesn't work when i implement google recaptcha. When the input is empty, the form is supposed not to be submitted. But the form gets submitted when input is empty. I followed [google's guide](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#auto_render) to implement that in its simplest form.

```
 <?php if (isset($_POST['code']) && ($_POST['code'] == "whatever")) //do stuff?> ?>
```

> What i want to do is to make the recaptcha execute only when the input is not empty, else prevent form submit and recaptcha execution.
>
> ```html
> <form id="form1" method="post" >
>  
>   <input name="code" type="text" required>
>
>   <button  data-sitekey="xxx" 
>       data-callback='onSubmit' type="submit" class="g-recaptcha" >Let me in</button>
>   </form>
> </div>
>       <script>
>        function onSubmit(token) {
>       document.getElementById("form1").submit();
>        }
>      </script>
> <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
> ```

Comment: Can you add some code of your validation?

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is 5 years old, but it's something that still happens and I'd like to share the most practical solution possible

Google's instructions are as follows:

```
<!-- In your form, change your submit button -->
<button class="g-recaptcha" 
        data-sitekey="PUT_YOUR_reCAPTCHA_SITE_KEY" 
        data-callback='onSubmit' 
        data-action='submit'>Submit</button>

<!-- Include the recaptcha api.js and create the onSubmit function -->
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
    <script>
        function onSubmit(token) {
            document.getElementById("YOUR_FORM_ID").submit();
        }
    </script>
```

In this way, you will lose the validation of the inputs, because the javascript function will bypass it.

But you can invoke the html validation directly by the javascript function as follows:

```
<script>
    function onSubmit(token) {

        var form = document.getElementById("YOUR_FORM_ID");
        if (form.checkValidity()) {
            form.submit();
        } else {
            grecaptcha.reset();
            form.reportValidity();
        }

    }
</script>
```

This way, html validation will continue to occur and display indications of mandatory fields. The form will only be sent if all mandatory fields are filled in correctly (form validated).

Credits: [@brandonaaron](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/issues/302#issuecomment-621794131)

Comment: This was extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

Looking over the documentation you linked to, you are probably better off getting rid of the `required` attribute and adding a check to your script to not submit  the form if the I put field is null.

So JavaScript would be checking if the field is empty and then give a validation alert or however works best for your situation.

Comment: the problem is that the form is submitted with php only, i am not using any JS for this

Comment: In that case, here is some PHP specific documentation for reCAPTCHA:
[reCAPTCHA 2.0 & PHP tutorial](https://www.kaplankomputing.com/blog/tutorials/recaptcha-php-demo-tutorial/),
[Google's PHP reCAPTCHA documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php)
Just know that the Google documentation has a warning at the top that it is geared toward v 1.0 and is no longer supported. But should get you going in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

The reason it submits is your JavaScript function is calling submit directly, which is bypassing the HTML5-only validation. The submit button being a type of 'submit' will do the submission for you automatically so you don't need it.